# Java NIO store list of Paths

Tags: java, nio

geniuses.

I'm practicing Java NIO.

I'm trying to store list of files under different parent directories.

So here is my code:

```
    ArrayList<Path> pathList = new ArrayList();
    Stream<Path> dirStream = Files.list(Paths.get("..."));
    dirStream.forEach((path) -> {
        pathList.add(Paths.get(path.toString(), "..."));
    });
```

I wonder if there are more fancy ways to do it.

e.g., store paths into a Stream<Path>.

Thanks for your lesson!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this

```
ArrayList<Path> pathList = Files.list(Paths.get("..."))
                                .map(path -> path.resolve("..."))
                                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```